# Flutter app Icon doesn't change when using flutter launcher icon package (with flavor)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have an app that uses flavor (very good cli), I want to change the app icon based on the flavor using `flutter launcher icon` package. I already run:

```
dart run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f flutter_launcher_icons
```

and the icon has already been added to the `android/app/src/flavor-name/res` but the icon doesn't even change. But every time I run the "dart run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f flutter_launcher_icons*" commands there's the result that says "`No Platform Provided`" in the image below:
[Command Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpIAe.png)

I already tried to delete the default app icon but it doesn't work. I also tried to run the command, uninstall the apps, and build again but it doesn't work. I always do "`flutter clean`" and "`flutter pub get`" too. I already made `.yaml` file based on the flavor and the code inside every .yaml. The file is like this:
[.yaml Flavor code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xihGk.png)

What should I do to solve this problem? Is the "`No Platform Provided`" result related to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
 
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter_launcher_icons: 
  android: ture
  ios: ture
  image_path: 'assets/images/iconlogo.png'
```

provide the icon path according to your app assets and after pug get, run this command in terminal

```
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

it will automatically generate the app icon for all devices.